# Is it possible to update a Telerik RadChart without it flickering?

Tags: asp.net, telerik

Is it possible to update the Chart without reloading the whole chart again and if so how?

My site flicker like this example from Telerik:
[link text](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/controls/examples/integration/aspajaxchartapplication/defaultcs.aspx?product=chart)

I'm using:
* Telerik RadChart (with horizontal bars)
* asp:timer
* updatepanel
* scriptmanager

Even just a point in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: It looks like its the Interval="10000", that make me go to page_load and not my tick method, but i'm not sure.

Comment: I think that this a problem by Telerik to fix it and the main problem is that they transmit a full image. I see the page and the flickering is very bad... why not try some other way to show your data ? see this http://www.highcharts.com/  as alternative for real data change

Comment: Ok then theres not much to do.

Because we are a bit committed with Telerik now :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a recent post in the forums on this:
http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/chart/chart-blinks-on-ajax-refresh.aspx